# Mod rewrite rule question/help

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects

I have the following ruleset in my .htaccess file which basically rewrites my php pages and makes them appear as subfolders, so for example, `http://www.mysite.co.uk/about-me/` points to `http://www.mysite.co.uk/about.php`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$

RewriteRule ^index.php$ /welcome-to-my-website/ [L,R=301,NC]
ReWriteRule ^welcome-to-my-website/$ index.php [NC,L]
ReWriteRule ^about-me/$ about.php [NC,L]
ReWriteRule ^my-portfolio/$ portfolio.php [NC,L]
ReWriteRule ^contact-us/$ contact.php [NC,L]
```

What I want to do is to automatically forward/redirect the root - http://www.mysite.co.uk/ - and the index.php page straight to /welcome-to-my-website/ via htaccess so that there is no duplicate content. Any idea how one may achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code redirects a user if index.php or root of a website is typed into the browser. If anyone can refine the following any further, please let us know. I really hope this helps someone save a lot of time and their sanity:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(|index\.php)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(|index\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/welcome-to-my-website/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, following 3 RewriteConds are not necessary, you can remove them:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
```

To redirect the root and index.php to /welcome-to-my-website/ you can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(|index\.php)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/welcome-to-my-website/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm either doing something wrong, or it is not working correctly. I took out the three rewriteconds and added in the rewrite rule you so kindly provided, but Firefox fails saying 'The page isn't redirecting properly'. Is there a specific place in the ruleset this needs to go - I tried moving it above and below the `ReWriteRule ^welcome-to-my-website/$ index.php [NC,L]` rule?

Comment: After spending most of last night trying different combinations, I finally found the answer. Thanks @Floern for your assistance.